# What's the difference between Gorm Save and Update?

Tags: go-gorm

What are the differences between these two ways of updating? Aside from the fact that the 1st way requires a query first. The docs say that updating the second way will ignore zero value fields. Is that also true of the 1st?

```golang
user = User{1, "old name"}
user2 = User{2, "old name"}

//fist way
db.First(&user)
user.Name = "new name"
db.Save(&user)

//second way
user2.Name = "new name"
db.Model(&user2).Updates(&user2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Gorm API documentation (https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm#DB.Save), Save function will create a Primary Key for an entity if it does not exist as well as update fields, while Update will just update fields.

Answer (score 4):

As per gorm's docs, `Updates` differs from `Save` in 2 ways:

1. It does not create an entity if it does not exist as mentioned before.
2. It only [updates non-zero values](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Updates-multiple-columns) so you can specify specify only the properties you need to update.

Comment: 2nd bullet is very important if you're trying to unset fields!